# How to prevent an entire class from be modified by proguard?

Tags: java, android, proguard

I need to keep com.package.app.helpers.GraphAdapterBuilder class

I tried with:

```
-keep class com.package.app.helpers.GraphAdapterBuilder
```

and

```
-keep class com.package.app.helpers.GraphAdapterBuilder.** { *; }
```

But it seems that it's not working. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
-keep class com.package.app.helpers.GraphAdapterBuilder { *; }
```

If `GraphAdapterBuilder` is only the one class in the package you also may try:

```
-keep class com.package.app.helpers.** { *; }
```

Comment: exactly the same problem, proguard is destroying the class